# Shared rising edge detector?

Tags: flipflop, memory, latch, register

Why do we have a rising edge detector in every flip flop of a register. Can't we just make a shared one for all the flip flops in order to save hardware?

Comment: How does it save hardware? Illustrate.

Comment: We don't have a "rising edge detector" in every flip-flop. Typically, we don't have a "rising edge detector" in **any** flip-flop. What makes you think that we do?

Comment: Your best chance to get a positive answer is, please: put your thoughts in drawings and elaborate on descriptions. Do not assume we are all on the same page. Whatever it is, I like the "different angle" you are looking at. Engineering owes a lot to that attitude.

Comment: Because as soon as you make things common, you limit applications.  And there are octal latches with common clocks.

Answer (score 2):

D FF's for example are designed/made using Transmission Gate FET switches (TG) and Inverters.

The front-end looks like a Sample and hold with back to back inverters providing positive feedback to hold the value.

In a Register with many FF's each input requires it's own ***"Sample and Hold" function*** where it holds on the rising edge of the clock.

[image]